# Can I change devices permissions with chmod?

Tags: linux, permissions, device

**Before read:** I don't want to use any udev rule.

I need to change (programmatically) the permissions of some device. But first in order to underestand what I have to do (in code) I want to make the job using just `chmod` command.

So far, I've tried this:

```
root# ls -l /dev/sdb
root# brw-rw-rw- 1 root disk 8, 16 Apr 7 05:27 /dev/sdb
root# chmod 0600 /dev/sdb 
root# ls -l /dev/sdb
root# brw------- 1 root disk 8, 16 Apr 7 05:27 /dev/sdb
```

as you can see, `/dev/sdb` has read and write permissions only for the owner (wich is root). But I'm still able to create new files and read files from my connected flash drive.

What I'm missing. How can I use `chmod` to prevent users to write to some device?

Can be done what I'm asking for?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand - you want to set permissions on your local OS that a flash drive will enforce? I don't see how that's supposed to work. You'd need special firmware or something on the flash drive to get this functionality.

Comment: This is what I want. I connect the flash drive, then linux creates the device special file for handle the flash drive (`/dev/sdb` in this case). And then I want to change the permissions on the newly created `/dev/sdb` so no user can access to it. Can that be done?

Comment: The permissions you create on your OS are enforced by your OS. You can't secure a portable drive at that level, it just doesn't work that way.

Comment: How do your users write files to a raw device?  I think you're confused.  The perms for the user to access a file-system DON'T come from the raw device, they come from the mount-point.